# Playframework 2.x (Scala): Passing a Twirl/HTML code from a controller's function to the view

Tags: javascript, playframework, twirl

**My Aim**: Learn the limitations (if any) on parameters that I can send from the controller to view. Right now, I'm checking if I can send any Twirl's keyword (e.g., @, @for, etc.) from the controller function to the view, and then reload a part of the page using JS.

We can pass a raw HTML to the view while using `as(HTML)` in a controller function. However is it possible to send a block of `scala.html` type code with all their syntax sugar from the controllers' function to views' related JS function; so that it can show it in the related div? For example how/can I can pass the following:

```
<p style="padding:1rem;"> @for(i <- items){<h2>i.name</h2} </p>
```

If I wrap the above in a controller function:

`Ok(<p style="padding:1rem;"> @for(i <- items){<h2>i.name</h2} </p>).as(HTML)`

Rightfully so, I will get the following error; as the code is not pure HTML:

[image]

So Is there a way? or all the template related engine's keywords can not be send from the controller to the view?; and only need to be used on the views' files.

Comment: Beyond your own aim to learn this, is there any specific use case you want to achieve? I am having a hard time figuring out the advantage of this approach.

Comment: @Anton it could be used as part of a faster streaming solution, obviously iff the ratio of server(s)/client(s) is not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

twirl code is compiled on server into regular scala functions (see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplateUseCases#Tags-%28they-are-just-functions,-right?%29 )

you can eg create a file like renderItems.scala.html

```
@(items: List[Item])
<p style="padding:1rem;"> @for(i <- items){<h2>@i.name</h2} </p>
```

and call it like

```
Ok(renderItems(items))
```

Comment: also here is an interesting approach you might find useful https://github.com/brikis98/ping-play

Comment: Thanks, going to Play! with it a little bit, and then update all, and if necessary this answer, on this.